# Are [cross-browser] and [portability] synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've written [a JavaScript-related question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/118272/64809), and I tagged it with [cross-browser](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-browser), but it was (for my unfortunate surprise) marked as [portability](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portability), which is its synonym master. And it wasn't just me who found that weird: [user 200_success also demonstrated to be unsure on what *portability* tag meant in my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118272/is-date-18-years-old#comment220206_118272), and despite both *might* appear to be interchangeable, they actually aren't, as we can note in their tag wiki descriptions:

> [**portability**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/portability/info)
>
> Portable code can be run with little to no modification in multiple
>   environments. Portable applications can be run from, for example, a
>   USB drive without modifying a computer's environment.
>
> [**cross-browser**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-browser/info)
>
> Cross-browser refers to the ability of a website, web application,
>   HTML construct or client-side script to function in environments that
>   provide its required features and to bow out or degrade gracefully
>   when features are absent or lacking.

We can also note disambiguation evidences in [Simon's comment](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6592/please-desynonymize-cross-browser-and-portability-tags#comment14933_6592) and [Joe's answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6596/64809).

What do you think about desynonymizing them? How could we handle that change?

Comment: In my opinion, you present a weak case. You may have a point, or not, but your question doesn't provide any research done on the matter. It's a simple "I disagree with the status quo, can we change it?" without arguments.

Comment: I can agree with this suggestion just by considering what I think that the words mean: Cross-browser means cross-browser compatibility, but portability mean portability across Operating Systems. While cross-browser might be considered the browsers' version of portability.

Comment: I've unlinked the [tag:portability] ← [tag:cross-browser] synonym. My point about your question still remains, though: if your question doesn't have a particular cross-browser compatibility concern, then there's no need to apply a [tag:cross-browser] tag. It would be just like any other question with browser-related code.

Answer (score 12):

If we look at Stack Overflow, to see the state of their tags.

- [Portability](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/portability/info)

  > Portable code can be run with little to no modification in multiple environments. Portable applications can be run from e.g. a USB drive without modifying a computer's environment.

  24 followers,
  1064 questions,
  6 asked this month, 99 this year.
- [Cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cross-browser/info)

  > Cross-browser development refers to the practice of building web sites, web applications, libraries, or components so that they function across different web browsers and rendering engines.

  261 followers,
  7227 questions,
  9 asked this week, 57 this month.
- [Cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cross-platform/info)

  > An attribute conferred to computer software or computing methods and concepts that are implemented and inter-operate on multiple computer platforms.

  223 followers,
  3735 questions,
  9 asked this week, 46 this month.

---

Portability seems to be aimed at a different task to both cross-browser and cross-platform.
It's meant for apps that need nothing installed on the users computer.
One where you say 'download and run this.'
Then you cut the folder onto a USB and it's now working *exactly the same* on your other computers.

You can have a portable app, that is not cross platform.
I.e a self contained C program that can only run on Windows.

You can also have a portable app, that is not cross browser.
I.e. a static website run from a USB, but only runs on one browser correctly.

I think that we should have all three of these tags.
As currently we have an odd meaning of portable.
And it's 'sub-tags' are more popular.

---

I looked at Stack Overflow as it has all three tags, and we don't even have a [portability tag wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/portability/info).

And I looked at cross-platform due to Simon's comment.

Comment: Exactly! Good answer!